# custom dropdown position react native

Tags: css, android-layout, react-native

I have created custom dropdown where I am getting all countries data, it's working fine but the layout is not correct. The first field of the form is country field, so the list should come under that.

What I have tried
1. Position relative and absolute
2. Margin and padding

Below is the code

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 15, position: 'relative' }}>
    <CustomPicker
        data={this.countryDs}
        source={require("../../resource/img/globe.png")}
        selectedValue={this.reg_country}
        onValueChange={this.onCountryChange.bind(this)}
        style={{ position: 'absolute',top:20 }}
     />
</View>
```

and below is the current output image

[image]

while I want

[image]

Comment: But, what is the problem? What should be the correct layout?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai The first field of the form is country field, so the list should come under that.